# Would you recommend a 301, 302 or something else?

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

Ok I have built a resort guide for a summer holiday destination. This is how I have structured the site.

```
www.domain.co.uk/resort-name-a/guide
www.domain.co.uk/resort-name-a/nightlife
etc.
```

Now, in my head I am future proofing the site, so I can add future resorts.

The sites front content is the same as the resort front page in so far I have only written one resort.

```
www.domain.co.uk
www.domain.co.uk/resort-name-a
```

Now what I will be doing is when I add a new resort, the front page will become a mix of both the resorts.

Before I have added any new resorts, what should I do with `www.domain-name.co.uk/resort-name-a`, 302 or 301...

`www.domain.co.uk/resort-name-a` to `www.domain.co.uk`

Comment: Will you be adding more resorts? If so, what is wrong with the structure you have?? I would not make the home page a duplicate of resort a if that is the case, however, you can have some level of overlap. If you intend to have more than one resort, then just update the home page to be more appropriate. If you are not adding more resorts then a 301 like you described could be appropriate. NOT a 302.

Comment: Its hard to explain. In the future the home page will be a mix of the latest news, events, businesses featured throughout the site. As for now, it is the  home page of the resort. I will be adding more resorts, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend expanding on your tree.

So far, you're on a good start with the first resort:

```
www.domain.co.uk/resort-name-a/guide
www.domain.co.uk/resort-name-a/nightlife
etc.
```

Now when you want to add another resort, use a similar structure:

```
www.domain.co.uk/resort-name-b/guide
www.domain.co.uk/resort-name-b/nightlife
etc.
```

Every time you add a resort, you should update the contents at:

www.domain.co.uk

so that there are links to all the resorts, and if the list is going to be huge, consider divide your links across pages and then you could have URLs like the following:

```
www.domain.co.uk/all-resorts/page-1
www.domain.co.uk/all-resorts/page-2
....
www.domain.co.uk/all-resorts/page-n
```

The only time a 301 should be used is if you're making URL changes to pages after having the previous URLs accessible to the internet, which in that case, the old pages should redirect to the new pages.

Answer (score 0):

> Before I have added any new resorts, what should I do with www.domain-name.co.uk/resort-name-a, 302 or 301...

This is a *temporary* situation so you should not be using a 301 "Permanent" redirect.

To be honest, I don't think you need (or should) do anything at all in this respect!

This is presumably a new site, so there might not be anything indexed yet. If you 302 (temporary) redirect from "resort-name-a" to your home page then the "resort" page will not get indexed, only your home page. It will be like the "resort" page does not exist, but presumably you have links pointing to this page. But the home page is going to change when you add more resorts, which is going to confuse users, so the "resort" page is really the canonical page (at this time).

You could redirect from the home page to to the "resort" page (the canonical page at this time) but then you're giving mixed signals. You do want the search engines to notice the home page. And users won't be able to easily bookmark your site URL. Maybe set a `rel="canonical"` to the "resort" page, but it's only temporary so it's a bit confusing.

Having two pages the same (duplicate content) isn't a "penalty", it will just mean the search engines will be pushed deciding which page to return in the SERPs - but it's only temporary. In bound links are going to be split, but so they should be, they are going to be two separate pages soon(?).

But there's still the question... even with just 1 "resort" why would the home page have exactly the same content? Be inventive, create some content.